# Timestamp url with function

Tags: python, api, http, python-3.x, url

I am trying to insert my function some 'int' that i get form "datetime"  url API.
First i am import the UNIX timestamp from the API,the data that i get is not a clean numbers so I need to divideit with casting function,so i will get only "numbers", i am getting a "1382310549" UNIX and convert it to a regular date,then I am asking only for the "year" and i get "2013" ,the problem is that my function give me back "none" instead of give me back what "2013" is equal and that is "wow"... 
Its looks like the function cannot understand what is (value.strftime('%Y')...

```
import urllib.request
import datetime
response3 = urllib.request.urlopen("https://blockchain.info/q/addressfirstseen/1LuckyR1fFHEsXYyx5QK4UFzv3PEAepPMK").read()

def type_conversion(val, to_type, default=None):
    try:
        return to_type(val)
    except ValueError:
        return default

def FirstTransaction(c):
        if c == 2013 :
            return  ('wow')
        elif c == 2010 :
            return  ('yeaaaa')

timestamp = (type_conversion(response3, int))
value = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
print(FirstTransaction(value.strftime('%Y')))
```

Tnx guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

value.strftime('%Y') gives you a string and not an int. Try either:

```
print(FirstTransaction(int(value.strftime('%Y'))))
```

or:

```
def FirstTransaction(c):
    if c == "2013" :
        return  ('wow')
    elif c == "2010" :
        return  ('yeaaaa')
```

Answer (score 0):

`value.strftime('%Y')` yields a string like `"2013"`. So you need to compare `c == "2013"` and `c == "2010"` within `FirstTransaction`.

By the way: You might want wo return some default string if `c` is not among 2013 or 2010. Currently, you implicitly return `None`.